# Are solar physics images of use to the night-time community?

Tags: sun, observational-astronomy

I'm actually interested in cases of cross-discipline data re-use.

I know that the [SOHO/LASCO coronographs](http://lasco-www.nrl.navy.mil/lasco.html) are used for [comet finding](http://sungrazer.nrl.navy.mil/), that solar telescopes were used to get information about [Venus's atmosphere during its solar transit in 2004](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2004/06/040604025320.htm), and STEREO were [rolled to try to look at L4 and L5](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2009/09apr_theia/).

But do the night-time or planetary communities use the images for anything else? For example, does [STEREO](http://stereo.gsfc.nasa.gov/)'s separation from Earth make the [coronographs](http://secchi.nrl.navy.mil/index.php?p=cor2) or [heliospheric imagers](http://www.sstd.rl.ac.uk/stereo/about-hi.html) useful for any triangulation, or are the exposure times or spatial resolution problematic, or is the relative separation insignificant in the grand scheme of things?

**Update**: I'm not interested in space weather or for warnings about when to put satellites into 'safe mode'... I'm more interested if the low-level telescope data is useful.

Answer (score 6):

I've been pondering your question for a couple of days, and the only answer I can think of from my own experience is that Coronal Mass Ejections trigger aurora on Earth, and aurora can seriously interfere with night-time observations of faint objects. I'm thinking of an occasion when I travelled to an extremely dark site in Algonquin Park and set up for a night of deep sky observing, only to be blasted by a brilliant aurora display!

Comment: Thanks ... Yes, I guess this isn't quite like the space weather case where it's a warning against observing, but a specific notification to start observing.